How to reassemble fragmented TCP packets with Scapy and also including Netfilter Queue (developing an IDS)
I am developing an IPS and using Scapy to parse the packets and to take actions based on the payloads present in the packet  . I am currently trying to implement Drop/Block functionality . Came across Netfilter Queue which will help me to drop/block the packet at the kernel level . When I am sniffing directly through Scapy I can mention Session as TCPStream which will handle the the task of reassembling TCP streams / segments , but if I use Netfilter queue the packets would pass through Netfilter Queue and converted into Scapy packets directly , how can I handle reassembling of Tcp streams /segments now?

First, TCP has segments, not packets. IPv4 packets may be fragmented, but are reassembled by IPv4. TCP segments data streams. Your terminology makes the question confusing. Are you wanting to reassemble IPv4 packets, or are you wanting to reconnect the TCP segment into a data stream? IPv4 and TCP operate at different layers in the network stack, so you cannot mix up the terminology and make sense.

@RonMaupin sorry, I want to reconnect the TCP segments into streams
